# Is there a bus connection between Narita airport and Tokyo Asakusa?

Tags: budget, buses, airport-transfer, tokyo, nrt

I'm trying to figure out how to get from Narita airport to Tokyo Asakusa.
The LP guide says there should be a very convenient bus by [Cab-Station Co](http://www.cab-station.co.jp) that only costs 1000 ¥.

I've tried to use the site above but it's somewhat difficult to navigate using google translator and I didn't manage to find the information I need.

The [official Narita airport site](http://www.narita-airport.jp/en/access/bus/#bus) doesn't seem to report anything like that, although [WikiTravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Narita#Get_in) says there should be a [Tokyo Shuttle](http://www.keiseibus.co.jp/global/en/nrt00.html/) operated by Keisei on the same price range even tho it doesn't stop in Asakusa.
[Narita's page on WikiVoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Narita) doesn't mention any bus.

I'm curious to know if there ***actually*** is a bus service run by Cab-Station Co.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They made a [press release](http://www.value-press.com/pressrelease/67740) in 2010 about this service. The advertised domain for this service, specially targeted at backpackers, does not exist anymore, so I would assume this service is discontinued.

If you are willing to pay a bit more (¥2,700), you can use the [Airport limousine bus](http://www.limousinebus.co.jp/area/narita/kinshicho_toyocho.html) to bring you from Narita to Asakusa.

Answer (score 3):

The [Keisei Skyliner](http://www.keisei.co.jp/keisei/tetudou/skyliner/us/fares/) also offers two more options which are cheaper than the Airport Limousine Bus.

They offer from Narita Terminal 1/2 a train to Asakusa for ¥1,280 (about $12.5) on the Narita Sky Access Line and ¥1,090 (about $10) on the Keisei Main Line.

Here's a [full PDF map](http://www.keisei.co.jp/keisei/tetudou/railmap/railmap.pdf) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Tokyo-Narita/Asakusa … there is a train for about $14 US, and a bus for about $25 US.

Comment: There is no direct train: you'd need to take the Keisei Ltd Express to Ueno and transfer to the Ginza metro line, which is a fairly lengthy hike.  The bus is the Airport Limousine bus that uncovery mentions.

Comment: I have no idea if it's accurate, but what Rome2Rio showed was a twelve-dollar Keisei Skyliner to Ueno, a walk of about 150 meters, then a two-dollar Tokyo Metro Ginza to Asakusa. They will also show it in yen if you ask for it.

Comment: That's roughly accurate, although said 150 meters is underground and (IIRC) involves a number of staircases.

Comment: Hmmm.  Not possible to go up to the surface, across, and back down again?  Zooming in, it looks like there are roads and sidewalks connecting that would stretch it out to about 200 meters.

Comment: Possible but unhelpful, as you'll need to tackle a staircase to get to the Ginza Line platform for Asakusa. http://www.tokyometro.jp/station/ueno/index.html